# Rational function on $\mathbb{P}^2$ whose square is identity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, rational-functions

Suppose $f:\mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^2$ is rational such that $f \circ f = \mathbb{Id}$. Then is it true that $f$ must be linear?

It feels true due to the degree which increases, but some things might cancel out.

Suppose we have a smooth curve $C$ of genus $g\geq 1$ with a rational function $g: C \to C$ with the same property. Does it always rise to an $f$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$ whose restriction is $g$? Does it imply that $g$ has to be linear too?
This on the other side seems wrong to me.

Comment: Have you tried the map $(xy,yz,zx)$?

Comment: Ok so $[YZ:XZ:XY]$ is a counterexample. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Mohan mentioned in the comments, there exist non-linear functions whose power is $\mathbb{Id}$.

For example $[x:y:z]\mapsto [yz:xz:xy]$ has order two, and $[x:y:z]\mapsto [xy:yz:zx]$ has order six.

Comment: I don't think your comments about the degrees of these maps are correct. If $f^{\circ 2} = \operatorname{id}$, then $f$ is birational, so it must have degree $1$. Maybe this can be seen more clearly for the first map if we divide through by $xyz$, which gives $[yz : xz : xy] = \left[\frac{1}{x} : \frac{1}{y} : \frac{1}{z}\right]$, which is valid when $xyz \neq 0$.

Comment: So you are saying that a map $f$ such that $f \circ f=id$ must have degree 1? Could you formulate that in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an involution

$$(x,y,z)\mapsto (x^2-yz, y^2-xz, z^2-xy)$$

It is the inversion wr to the conic $x y + x z + x z=0$ with inversion center $(1,1,1)$ ( the Hirst transform, see @Jean Marie: [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286648/if-fracx2-yza2-bc-fracy2-zxb2-ca-fracz2-xyc2-ab-prove-th/4287417#4287417)).

Projective rational involutions  appear in other instances, think of the map $A \mapsto A^{-1}$ for matrices, which in projective coordinates can be given as $A \mapsto \operatorname{adj} A$, from a matrix to its [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix). This map, restricted to certain subalgebras of matrices, again gives an involution.

Still, I cannot find any rational involutions of $\mathbb{P}^2$ of degree $>2$. Also, I can't find rational involutions of $\mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $> n$.